# Using video/image files in C

Tags: c, io, jpeg, mpeg

I'm trying to look through and find a way to annotate a video in C with polygons bounding boxes, however I'm stuck at a very elementary step.

Assuming I know how to break a .MPEG movie up into multiple JPEG images, how do I manipulate that file in C? The things I'll eventually need to draw on are text, points, and lines, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to get started with this.

If I declare:

```
FILE* img = fopen('foo.jpeg', 'r');
```

then what could I do with `img`? Is there a way to access certain pixels in the drawing?

Answer (score 0):

What you did in your code sample is just opening a file. You didn't even read any data from it yet.

The simplest way to load an image file is to use dedicated library, such as [SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html).
If you weren't able to do it by yourself, however, I really don't think you will be able to accomplish your project goals - it is really advanced stuff you want to create, and you failed, as you already noticed, on the most basic of steps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My boss told me to do this, and this job is paying for my school. Don't feel to qualified myself.